# Editor appears as author in list of questions

Tags: bug, attribution, question-lists

I just edited and answered the question [Solr search part sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538779/solr-search-part-sentence).

> [image]

Now as I went back to the list of questions for [solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solr), I noticed that I appeared as the author of the question. I would have expected the original author instead of me within the list. Probably me aside of him, just as it is within the question.

To me the way it currently is looks like I have asked the question. I feel that this is somewhat confusing.

> [image]

Comment: asked and answered at MSE: [Why on question listing page, user and reputation shown are those of the last editor?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145871/why-on-question-listing-page-user-and-reputation-shown-are-those-of-the-last-ed)

Answer (score 4):

The tab you're looking at is "Recently Active 'solr' Questions".

It's showing the most recent activity on that question is you **modifying** it 3 minutes ago... I'm not sure why you think it should be the author there instead.

<s>Note that if the most recent activity on the question was it being *asked*, then the verb above the user would be **asked** rather than **modified**.</s> It turns out that the verb is *always* *modified*. Even if the last activity was it being asked. This may be a bug, but my main point remains.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Too few coffee today. I did not enter over the bookmark, but over the firefox new-tab. Sorry, for the confusion.